# Why is RAISERROR misspelled? Or is it not?

Tags: t-sql

Why isn't `RAISERROR` spelled `RAISEERROR`?  Where is the second E?  I could understand if it were some ancient keyword length constraint, but I wouldn't expect it to be a nine-character limit.

Is RAIS or RROR a technical word such that "raise-error" is just a mis-reading?  Are its (immediate) origins in a different language?

I've searched Google but not finding much on the subject.

Comment: What was really confusing me is that SSMS colors `RAISEERROR` pink and `RAISERROR` blue.

Comment: It's on a date with the N from loginame (courtesy of sp_who output) and I think P is trying to get in on the action too, courtesy of sp_helprotect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interesting - I've honestly never even noticed that before.

I would suspect that it's an early oversight that was just never corrected, though I'm a little surprised that support wasn't later added for RAISEERROR, with the mis-spelling left alone for compatibility.

Update: Aparently, there's even some internal confusion about what it ought to be - Check out [this connect request](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/112750/raiserror-error), though MSFT didn't respond to it.

Comment: Funny that they closed it as "not reproducible".  I just hit the "I can reproduce this" button on the Connect page.

Comment: Funny that they deleted it.

Comment: Unfortunately the connect is deprecated and can't find that address through [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/112750/raiserror-error)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same question which is why I stumbled across this post. From what I can see there actually is a difference and the spelling isn't the only thing different between the two cases. These two functions are not equivalent because of the usage.

**Links and colors**

- [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) - Has an MSDN link and it is colored cyan/blue in
  SSMS
- RAISEERROR - Doesn't have an MSDN link from what I can find
  right now and it is colored magenta in SSMS

Credit where credit is due - the color observation was raised already by user [Sahuagin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621316/sahuagin) in the comments under the question above.

**Are you using SQL Server 2012?**
Before I move on I think it is fair to state that if you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, DO NOT USE RAISERRROR! You should be using [THROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx).

**So what's the difference?**
You can use RAISERROR (blue) in a single inline statement, versus using RAISEERROR (magenta) which depends on being contained inside of different code block it seems like; based on the error that is returned. The exact syntax error is the following:

> Incorrect syntax near 'RAISEERROR'. Expecting CONVERSATION, DIALOG,
>   DISTRIBUTED or TRANSACTION.

**RAISERROR Example (One E - blue)**

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(200)
SET @foo = ''

IF NULLIF(@foo, '') IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- To fix this line, remove one "E" to read RAISERROR
    RAISEERROR('Not enough Vespene Gas!', 16, 1);

    RETURN -- This is required otherwise execution will continue!
END

-- You need the RETURN above or this will execute
SELECT Critical_TSqlLine = 1;
```

[image: This is what happens when I execute this block of code.]

Now if you just remove one "E" from the above code, that will function just fine. I didn't provide the execution results, but if you open up SSMS and drop that in and execute I guarantee it will work.

**RAISEERROR Example (Two Es - magenta)**
I spent entirely too much time trying to figure out how to use this version of the function and I cannot provide an example where this will actually work. I looked into using CONVERSATION, DIALOG, DISTRIBUTED or TRANSACTION and I couldn't get the syntax to work. Long story short, don't concern yourself with this version just use the single E version. For those of you using SQL Server 2012, this shouldn't concern you anymore anyhow.

Comment: I suspect it's a typo somewhere in the syntax highlighting, some table of function names or whatever, making SSMS think there's a function with that name when there really isn't.

Comment: Possibly, my inkling is that it is an internal function that was never meant for the general user population to use - much like the sp_msforeach. They have weird naming conventions for things they use internally I have seen.

Comment: The two-`E` version isn’t actually a thing. You’re just triggering a compilation error due to using identifier literal syntax without having an object (e.g., table) of that name…

Comment: This is indeed a very long answer just to illustrate what was clear in the question: the two-`E` version doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10):

From [Getting feedback / progress from batches and stored procedures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2009/05/11/getting-feedback-progress-from-batches-and-stored-procedures/) by Jens K. Suessmeyer:

> Ever asked yourself why there is only one "e" in Raiserror? That is from the old Sybase days where two [of the same] same character were cut back to only [one]

Comment: If that was the case then shouldn't it be "RAISEROR"?

Answer (score 7):

why is there still a `TIMESTAMP` data type? support for old versions.   Someone Sybase person long ago decided to make it RAISERROR and not RAISEERROR, when Microsoft [made a deal with Sybase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#History) they continued the trend.

Comment: @Ardman, yeah fixed it, I typed it so many times as `RAISERROR` I couldn't do it as `RAISEERROR`!

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's intentional in that it is actually easier to read RAISERROR vs RAISEERROR.  (see also sp_helprotect for another example), especially when there's no distinction based on case.

This stuff goes way back into Sybase's history.

Answer (score 0):

During the development of Transact-SQL it was still common to omit vowels in written text. (The Torah was written without vowels.) That, however, is not the cause of the confusion.

[Ra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra), the Egyptian Sun god, battled every night with the serpent [Apep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apep), the Enemy of Ra (or Lord of Chaos). (Ref. [The Journey of the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra#The_journey_of_the_Sun).) If Apep were to win the battle then the Sun would not rise and the Earth would be left in darkness. With great foresight, T-SQL provided for that possibility with the statement in question.

In Pascal-case it should be written `RaIsError`.

Unrelated to the transition of T-SQL from Sybase to Microsoft is [`PowersHell`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). Winner of the MMVI Truth In Advertising Award and leaving us in darkness.

Comment: Clever! But not useful.