# sp_who: why 'loginame' with only one 'n'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Why does **sp_who** return a column called "loginame" and not "loginname" ?

One 'n' instead of two?

Typo ? English spelling rules? Or does it mean something else ?

Comment: Why `raiserror` only has one `e`?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yes, same question. Why ? Nerd's fun ?

Comment: The link in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16990998/73226 claims that was the standard in Sybase days.

Comment: Being dyslexic both examples look the same to me ,

Comment: @MartinSmith But if the sybase story is true, why is it then ERROR and not EROR ? ;)

Comment: Because clearly the convention is that the letters get collapsed where the final character of the preceding word is the same as the initial one of the next word.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean something else?

**Nope**! According to the [docs on `sp_who`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql):

> `loginame` `nchar(128)` - Login name associated with the particular process